# Generating database in Symfony2

Tags: database, symfony

How to generate a database from Symfony's existing code through command line ?

we have an existing code with us we need to do a type of reverse engineering to 
generate the database tables related to that code
we have tried commands like:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

We are new to Symfony....!

Comment: What do you mean by "existig code"?  Is it Doctrine 2 entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
is the right one
also you can dump sql queries with --dump-sql

Comment: we tried all command from http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html  but is it possible do it vice versa i mean generate database from code (entity)

Answer (score 3):

`app/console doctrine:database:create` then followed by `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`